# NextJS 13: Invalidating sidebar server component in chat app

Tags: caching, next.js, next.js13

Full minimal reproducable repo is [here](https://github.com/paulwongx/nextjs-sidebar-cache-issue).

This is a chat app with these routes:

- /chat

  - layout.tsx - server component that houses `Sidebar` which is also a server component
- /chat/[id] - client component

Whenever I update the data in my `Input` component, the sidebar doesn't update even with all of the commands below:

```
router.refresh();
router.push("/chat/" + chatId);
```

I even have a special route to invalidate the cache on the server side which calls `revalidatePath("/chat", "layout")` but the sidebar still doesn't update.

However, it's weird because in my `Sidebar` server component, the shows that it updates but the UI just doesn't update for some reason.

Below are some of the key code snippets, but the full reproducible code is in the repo.

```js
// ./app/chat/layout.tsx

import React from 'react'
import { Sidebar } from "./_sidebar"

export default async function Layout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
  return (
    <div className="relative w-screen min-h-screen flex justify-start">
      <Sidebar />
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
// ./app/chat/_sidebar
import { getChats } from "@/actions";
import Link from "next/link";

export async function Sidebar() {
  const chats = await getChats();
  console.log("Sidebar.chats.latest", chats.at(-1))

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-full px-6 min-h-screen">
      <h2 className="font-bold underline">Sidebar</h2>
        <Link href="/chat">New Chat</Link>
        {chats.map((chat, index) => (
          <p className="whitespace-nowrap" key={index}>{chat.message.slice(0,20)}</p>
         ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
// ./app/chat/_input.tsx

"use client";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React from "react";

export function Input() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const inputRef = React.useRef<any>();

  return (
    <div className="absolute bottom-1/2 flex flex-col h-28">
      <div className="flex flex-col space-y-8">
        <label className="text-white">Input Field Below:</label>
        <textarea ref={inputRef} className="text-black w-96 h-48" />
        <button
          className="bg-green-900 px-6 py-3"
          onClick={async () => {
            const value = inputRef?.current.value;
            const chatId = nanoid();
            await fetch("/api/chats/update", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({ id: chatId, message: value }),
            }).then(res => res.json());

            await fetch(`/api/revalidate?path=/chat&type=layout`, {cache: "no-store"});
            router.refresh();
            router.push("/chat/" + chatId);
         }}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why can't you define a global state store?...You can use zustand or redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround: just swap the `router.push` and `router.refresh` rows.
And maybe it doesn't need to call `revalidatePath`.

The code below is an example.

```js
<button
    className="bg-green-900 px-6 py-3"
    onClick={async () => {
        const value = inputRef?.current.value;
        const chatId = nanoid();
        await fetch("/api/chats/update", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id: chatId, message: value }),
        }).then(res => res.json());
        router.push("/chat/" + chatId);
        router.refresh();
    }}
>
    Submit
</button>
```